Displacement thickness derivation in the Von Kármán momentum integral
The Von Kármán momentum integral is
$${\displaystyle {\frac {\tau _{w}}{\rho U^{2}}}={\frac {1}{U^{2}}}{\frac {\partial }{\partial t}}(U\delta _{1})+{\frac {\partial \delta _{2}}{\partial x}}+{\frac {2\delta _{2}+\delta _{1}}{U}}{\frac {\partial U}{\partial x}}+{\frac {v_{w}}{U}}}$$
with $${\displaystyle \tau _{w}=\mu \left({\frac {\partial u}{\partial y}}\right)_{y=0},\quad v_{w}=v(x,0,t),\quad \delta _{1}=\int _{0}^{\infty }\left(1-{\frac {u}{U}}\right)\,dy,\quad \delta _{2}=\int _{0}^{\infty }{\frac {u}{U}}\left(1-{\frac {u}{U}}\right)\,dy}$$
The displacement thickness is $\delta_1$.
I want to derive it using the continuity equation
$$Q_1=v_\delta y_0B=Q_2=\int_{0}^{\delta}udyB$$

1.
$$v_\delta y_0=\int_{0}^{\delta}udy$$
2. Add to both sides $-v_\delta \delta$
$$v_\delta y_0-v_\delta \delta=\int_{0}^{\delta}udy-v_\delta \delta$$
3. Divide by $v_\delta$
$$y_0- \delta=\int_{0}^{\delta}\frac{u}{v_\delta}- \delta dy$$
$$y_0- \delta=-\int_{0}^{\delta}\delta-\frac{u}{v_\delta}dy$$
4. $\delta_{1}=\delta-y_0$ is the displacement thickness and we obtain
$$\delta-y_0=\int_0^\delta(\delta-\frac{u}{v_\delta})dy$$
$$\delta_1=\int_0^\delta(\delta-\frac{u}{v_\delta})dy$$
But I should get
$$\delta _{1}=\int _{0}^{\delta}\left(1-{\frac {u}{v_\delta}}\right)\,dy,$$
Why is there a $\delta$ under my integral sign?
